# Beamer: multiple references to the same footnote

Tags: beamer, footnotes

In the [LaTeX wikibook](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX) I found a [workaround for having multiple references to the same footnote](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Footnotes_and_Margin_Notes#Common_problems_and_workarounds):

```
First reference.\footnote{This is the footnote}\addtocounter{footnote}{-1}\addtocounter{Hfootnote}{-1}
Second reference.\footnotemark
```

However, when using the beamer package and placing a footnote in the following context

```
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
% ...

\begin{block}{testblock}
    one program\footnote{open-source software}\addtocounter{footnote}{-1},
    other program\footnotemark
\end{block}
```

this trick doesn't work (as the second reference is '0' instead of 'a'). What's the best way to achieve this with beamer (it seems that the problem is that beamer uses another counter for the 'footnotes' inside the block environment and \footnotemark returns the regular counter)?

Comment: PS: I hope that $^a$ isn't the best workaround for this.

Comment: The only way that I can get the second reference to be `0` instead of *anything* is if I have `\addcounter{footnote}{-1}` *twice*.  Did you really put `Hfootnote` in the second `\addcounter`?

Comment: PS I added the links to make it easier for others to find the original source of the advice.

Comment: Thanks for the links. I actually use \addcounter{footnote}{-1} once which sets the counter to 0 since it was never incremented b/c it appears that beamer uses another counter for the footnotes inside blocks.

Comment: Given your remark to Marco below, can you please include a **full** working example, preamble and all.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `Hfootnote` counter is needed for articles because hyperref plays fast and loose with the internals and has its own counters for many things, including footnotes.  So when changing a counter in a non-normal fashion, you also have to change the hyperref version, which is usually `H<original counter name>`.

However, this is only needed when hyperref is making links between things in the document.  In this case, it isn't.  Beamer turns off much of hyperref's stuff as it loads the package with `implicit=false`.  If you look carefully at the resulting PDF of a beamer presentation with footnotes, you'll see that there are no hyperlinks on footnotes.

So the internal footnote stuff isn't installed, and this is why Marco gets the error that he does: `Hfootnote` isn't defined.

Thus, in fact, the *original* solution from the [LaTeX WikiBook](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Formatting#Footnotes) works absolutely fine in this context:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{block}{testblock}
    one program\footnote{open-source software},
    other program\footnotemark[\value{footnote}],
    third program\footnote{proprietry}
\end{block}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Indeed, this is a far more robust version since if you want more references to the same footnote, you can easily just copy that line:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{block}{testblock}
    one program\footnote{open-source software},
    other program\footnotemark[\value{footnote}],
    other program\footnotemark[\value{footnote}],
    third program\footnote{proprietry}
\end{block}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

This would *not* work with the `\addtocounter` hack, you'd need to `\addtocounter{footnote}{-1}` after each use of the footnotemark.  However, this still doesn't work with out-of-order footnotes, to do that you'd need to save the footnote marker.  Here's a simple hack for that, though I wouldn't be surprised to learn that there's a package to do it more cleanly (and that can cope with saving more than one footnote at a time).

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\alph{footnote}}
\newcommand{\savefootnote}{\edef\tmpfn{\the\value{footnote}}}
\newcommand{\savedfootnote}{\footnotemark[\tmpfn]}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{block}{testblock}
    one program\footnote{open-source software}\savefootnote,
    other program\savedfootnote,
    fourth program\savedfootnote,
    third program\footnote{proprietry}
    other program\savedfootnote
\end{block}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

---

(Note: As this answer has been accepted, and as nothing in the above is actually *wrong*, I'm adding this rather than deleting the above and replacing it.  However, the below is a more accurate analysis and more suitable fix.  I still don't claim any elegance, though.)

After a bit of digging, I've discovered that this is nothing to do with beamer whatsoever and everything to do with `minipage`s.  The reason that you are seeing this is because when beamer does fancy boxes then the contents get put inside a minipage.  Minipages have their own setup for footnotes and so within a minipage we have to hook in to the minipage system instead of the usual one.  In particular, minipage footnotes have their own counter, `mpfootnote`, and this is the one that should be saved.  At the start of the minipage environment, the old footnote stuff is replaced by the minipage-specific stuff.  This should mean that everything *just works*.  Except that it doesn't, because whoever designed the minipage environment didn't think that someone would want to use the `\footnotemark` command with an optional argument so the particular bit that that calls isn't swapped.

Fortunately, it's not hard to swap that bit if we need it.  Unfortunately, I can't see a way to test if we're in a minipage so we need to define a different command to save the footnote inside a minipage (or a block) to outside.  Maybe some passerby will be able to correct this.

Here's a sample code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\savefootnote}{%
\edef\tmpfn{\the\value{footnote}}}
\newcommand{\savempfootnote}{%
    \let\@xfootnotemark=\@mpxfootnotemark
\edef\tmpfn{\the\value{footnote}}}
\newcommand{\savedfootnote}{\footnotemark[\tmpfn]}
\def\@mpxfootnotemark[#1]{%
  \begingroup
  \c@footnote #1\relax
  \unrestored@protected@xdef\@thefnmark{\thempfootnote}%
  \endgroup
  \@footnotemark}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

    one program\footnote{open-source software}\savefootnote,
    one program\savedfootnote,
    one program\savedfootnote,
    other program\footnote{proprietry},
    one program\savedfootnote,
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
    one program\footnote{open-source software}\savempfootnote,
    one program\savedfootnote,
    one program\savedfootnote,
    other program\footnote{proprietry},
    one program\savedfootnote,
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Apparently it's the style I use that uses alphabetical counters inside blocks. The problem occurs, for example, with \usetheme{CambridgeUS}.

Comment: grand, this works :) (I had forgotten to copy the part you added to the preamble)

Comment: @Gerald: I've done some more investigating and found the source of the problem.  It's actually nothing to do with beamer and everything to do with minipage.  I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 5):

If you had made a minimal working example, you would have seen that the counter `Hfootnote` isn't defined.

```
\listfiles
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{block}{testblock}
    one program\footnote{open-source software}\addtocounter{footnote}{-1},
    other program\footnotemark
\end{block}
\begin{block}{testblock}
    one program\footnote{open-source software},
    other program\footnotemark[\value{footnote}]
\end{block}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: I have actually made a 'working' example (hence I know that the solution doesn't work (though I should have removed the Hfootnote above). So the solution you propose still leaves the first footnote as "a" and the second (the mark) as "0".

Comment: @Gerald: I edited my post. I get the correct result. ??

Comment: I see. I guess it's my style that uses alphabetic counters instead of numeric ones and hence causes the problem.

Comment: @Gerald: Use the commands of Andrew. `\value` should work.