# Reference different places to the same footnote

Tags: cross-referencing, footnotes

I want to make `footnotes` both at `Sentence 1` and `Sentence 2` (which are on the same page) to the `same footnote`.

For example, Wikipedia's "References" have this effect.

Comment: You might also want to look at the `endnotes` package. It places all footnotes at the end of the document.

Comment: Related question with the same problem in `beamer` (don't know if that counts as a duplicate): http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27763/beamer-multiple-references-to-the-same-footnote

Comment: possible dublicate:
[http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10102/multiple-references-to-the-same-footnote-with-hyperref-support-is-there-a-bett](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10102/multiple-references-to-the-same-footnote-with-hyperref-support-is-there-a-bett)

Comment: Perhaps you would like to switch to numbered (and footnoted) referencing style, using BibLaTeX?

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/10116/25653. This answer works well and just requires `cleveref`, which is worthwhile.

Answer (score 258, accepted):

You could do this (tested in `article` and `amsart`):

```
Text with first footnote\footnote{\label{note1}This is the labeled footnote}
and more text with a second footnote\footnote{here}.

In this new paragraph we have a reference to the first
footnote\footnotemark[\ref{note1}].
```

The result will be

[image: Footnotes as per above code example]

Edit: Further testing reveals, that the above solution fails when footnotes are numbered with anything other regular numbers. This is due to the fact, that the argument to `\footnotemark` is the value of a counter. Placing

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand\footnoteref[1]{\protected@xdef\@thefnmark{\ref{#1}}\@footnotemark}
\makeatother
```

in the preamble will allow us to mend the above example allowing any numbering of the footnotes.

```
Text with first footnote\footnote{\label{note1}This is the labeled footnote}
and more text with a second footnote\footnote{here}.

In this a paragraph we have a reference to the first footnote\footnoteref{note1}.
```

Edit 2: This will cause a problem when using `hyperref` where the link created by the `\footnoteref`macro points to the previous footnote and not to the referenced footnote. Using the package `cleveref` as in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10102/multiple-references-to-the-same-footnote-with-hyperref-support-is-there-a-bett/10116#10116) seems to be the perfect fit.

Comment: Thanks spet! But when I add `\usepackage[pdftex]{hyperref}` to the preamble, the red square of the last footnote is not displayed properly. Do you mind giving some hints?

Comment: @Covi: I'm not all that familiar with the internals of `hyperref` but I suspect that the problem is, that the link is constructed from the value of the `footnote` counter and not the value associated with the label given to \footnoteref. I think we need an expert on the subject to solve this :)

Comment: @Covi: DO NOT provide a driver to `hyperref`. It is smart enough to do this by itself, and a wrong driver will cause a lot of trouble.

Comment: @Covi: Have a look at [Multiple references to the same footnote with hyperref support - is there a better solution?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10102/multiple-references-to-the-same-footnote-with-hyperref-support-is-there-a-bett). It looks like it would be helpful.

Comment: This [second answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10102/multiple-references-to-the-same-footnote-with-hyperref-support-is-there-a-bett/10116#10116) to @MartinScharrer's link works for me. I will edit the above answer.

Comment: @MartinScharrer Driver?  @spet I've tried that solution and got `??` in the output, even though I compile multiple times and even comment out `\crefformat{footnote}{#2\footnotemark[#1]#3}`.

Comment: @Covi: The `pdftex` is the driver. If you use `pdflatex` it is used automatically, but with other compilers it causes trouble. So don't use it manually.

Comment: @Covi: `cleveref` is on my updated installation of TeX Live 2011 dated 2011/03/22, where a copy/paste of the referenced solution works. Are you running an updated installation? If so, I think you should contact the maintainer of `cleveref` because it sounds like a bug to me.

Comment: I can't seem to make this solution work. Always get a an error message `You can't use a prefix with \`the character @'.` :\

Comment: thank you for the solution. But in case I want to use footcite, how can I combine it together with footnote? I have used \footnote{\label{note1}\footcite{Dresden}} for example, in the footnote it shows the citation, but it has extra brackets (author, book) outside of the cited information. How can I eliminate the brackets? Thank you!

Comment: +1 for the comment at the end "Using the package cleveref as in this answer seems to be the perfect fit.". It worked smoothly with `hyperref`. Thanks!

Comment: Hello @spet Can you post a complete example please (packages etc)?

Comment: I am using Revtex4-1, natbib and hyperref, and I get a strange result: I get no error messages and the hyperlink does appear (as it should), but there is no number insdie it! Namely, I see a small red mark, meaning that that there is a hyperlink, but not e.g. [29]. Any advice please?

Comment: I suggest to move the Edit answer to the top (the first answer did not worked for me).

Answer (score 110):

**Objection, your honor:**

Have you ever seen that in a book? Probably not. Because: Two footnotemarks numbered with e.g. an "8" raise the question whether it is a typo. But your readers can not come and ask you, if you really meant to do it this way.

Please, if you'd like to refer to the same text, make a footnote saying (maybe in better English than mine):

> ¹ Long sentence at: Wallace, Infinite Jest, p. 1234.
>
> ² See footnote 1.

What you'd like to do is against an old and sensible tradition. It neither an excuse that a part of Wikipedia does it, nor that it is technically possible.

Comment: In general I have the same opinion about this as you, but for example this is really common for affiliations:

Smith, A. ^1, Miller, B. ^2, Williams, C. ^1 ---


1 Institute for Research on Footnotes, A-town.

2 Footnotes Reasearch & Developement, Inc., B-town.

(especially if there is a list of 20 authors with 14 affiliations, and some of the authors have even more than one affiliation.)

Comment: @KeksDose: Good point. Where do I get the number for the referenced footnote?

Comment: @DerMike In the answer above you find `\labe{footn:on-something}`. Just put that (not tested, though) in the footnote you'd like make a reference to.

Comment: @KeksDose typo: `label`

Comment: Another application is footnote in tables, as mandated e.g. in the Physical Review style. It can help distinguish the way different values are obtained while not obstructing the main purpose of the table (comparing them).

Comment: Imagine you have a table with many rows, and you want to point out that several cell entries are similar in some way (e.g. are all pain killers, or are all diabetes medication). Then you use a footnote "pain killers", to which all footmarks 1 point, a footnote "diabetes medication", to which all footmarks 2 point. Just because you can't imagine a use case, it doesn't mean that one does not exist.

Comment: @Ataxias Did you read the question? »For example, I want to make footnotes both at Sentence 1 and Sentence 2 (which are on the same page) to the same footnote«. Notes to table entries are a different thing. Explanations in a map as well.

Comment: @KeksDose The title is "Reference different places to the same footnote", so very general. The question starts with "For example, ...", so it's just an example use case. I agree with you that the particular example was not a good use case of the technical feature, but a good answer would answer how the objective can be technically achieved,  and then comment that "however, this example is not a good use case". Don't forget that people searching for this feature would land on this page, and they may have legitimate use cases in mind.

Comment: Reader need not wonder! If using a typesetting system such as LaTeX, that automates numbering of footnotes, then it is pretty obvious that the author went out of their way to repeat a specific reference.

The OP did not ask “*should* I do this“, but “*how* to do this”. The answer cannot be an editorial opinion (although such recommendation may constitute a side note to an actual, technical answer).

Comment: @KeksDose Tested, `\label{footn:on-something}` works for footnotes as well. Thanks!

Comment: Here is an example were this happens, paper in logic Untersuchungen uber die Axiome des Klassenkalkuls und iiber Produktations- und Summationsprobleme, welche gewisse Klassen von Aussagen betreffen, of Thoralf Skolem

Answer (score 106):

I'm a bit surprised that noone mentioned [KOMA-Script](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/koma-script)'s `\footref` before. The [KOMA-Script manual](http://texdoc.net/pkg/scrguien.pdf) also has an example where multiple reference to the same footnote could make sense:

> Maybe you have to mark each trade name with a footnote which states
>   that it is a registered trade name.

One could think of other similar cases…

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\begin{document}

Company SplishSplash\footnote{This is a registered trade name.
All rights are reserved.\label{refnote}}
produces not only SplishPlump\footref{refnote}
but also SplishPlash\footref{refnote}.

\end{document}
```

This functionality can be used with the standard classes by using `scrextend`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scrextend}
\begin{document}

Company SplishSplash\footnote{This is a registered trade name.
All rights are reserved.\label{refnote}}
produces not only SplishPlump\footref{refnote}
but also SplishPlash\footref{refnote}.

\end{document}
```

The documentclass [`memoir`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/memoir) already has its own `\footref`:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\begin{document}

Company SplishSplash\footnote{This is a registered trade name.
All rights are reserved.\label{refnote}}
produces not only SplishPlump\footref{refnote}
but also SplishPlash\footref{refnote}.

\end{document}
```

And for completeness' sake: the [`footmisc`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/footmisc) package also defines `\footref`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{footmisc}
\begin{document}

Company SplishSplash\footnote{This is a registered trade name.
All rights are reserved.\label{refnote}}
produces not only SplishPlump\footref{refnote}
but also SplishPlash\footref{refnote}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\footref{refnote}` worked perfect for me, even when inside a table!

Comment: `footmisc` package also has `\footref`

Comment: When I run this the repeated notes show a double questions mark instead of the footnote number.

Comment: @Keivan you a) need a `\label` in the right place and b) must at least compile twice!

Comment: This appears to conflict with href.

Comment: @clements  in my case it sends me to page 1, no matter what. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Just an FYI, the `scrextend` package works fine with `report`, but it causes conflicts with ACM's template for conference papers: https://www.acm.org/publications/proceedings-template 
Specifically, I got an error `Command \@subtitlefont already defined.`. Luckily the `footmisc` package works with the ACM template.

Answer (score 34):

I found a rather simple way to  do this. 
Just place a label inside the first footnote, and where you want your second reference you make insert a cross reference to that label in superscript, to make it look like a footnote

```
    line1 \footnote{text bla bla \label{xx}}
    line2 \textsuperscript{\ref{xx}}
```

Comment: This seems to be a slight variation of [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/35044/510) answer.

Comment: This becomes a problem when there's a page break between the two lines.

Comment: `\textsuperscript` doesn't match the font of `\footnote` in general, although at least this answer doesn't conflict with other packages.

Answer (score 25):

The [Wikibook LaTeX](http://en.wikibooks.org/w/index.php?title=LaTeX/Formatting&oldid=2200420#Common_problems_and_workarounds) provides an answer to this question:

> To make multiple references to the same footnote, you can use the
>   following syntax:
>
> ```
> Text that has a footnote\footnote{This is the footnote} looks like this.
> Later text referring to same footnote\footnotemark[\value{footnote}] uses
> the other command.
> ```
>
> If you need hyperref support, use instead:
>
> ```
> Text that has a footnote\footnote{This is the footnote}
> \addtocounter{footnote}{-1}\addtocounter{Hfootnote}{-1} looks like this.
> Later text referring to same footnote\footnotemark uses the other command.
> ```
>
> Note that these approaches don't work if there are
>   other footnotes between the first reference and any of the other
>   "duplicates".

Comment: This works even within the beamer-class

Answer (score 13):

The package `fixfoot` make just that,   specially designed for footnotes that appears very often, but in a page-by-page basis. This way the reader never need to go back to read a footnote, but never is printed more than once in the same page.

Each repeated footnote must be pre-declared and  invoked with their own custom command (e.g. `\repnote`) in the  preamble or the document environment. Note that duplicates of the footnote appear in the first compilation. You need two compile at least twice. Note also that in next pages the footnote could appear again but with a higher count:

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a5paper,paperheight=3.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fixfoot}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\DeclareFixedFootnote{\repnote}{ This is a repated footnote} 
\begin{document}
Text with first footnote\repnote\ and more text with a 
second normal footnote.\footnote{ This is a single footnote} 
Now again the first footnote.\repnote
\newpage
Again the first note \repnote  and another  footnote\footnote{ 
This is a another footnote}, and finally the fixed footnote\repnote.
\end{document}
```

If you do not want use `\repnote\` to maintain the space between words, you can use the starred version (`\DeclareFixedFootnote*`) that automatically insert a `\xspace` (however, the `xspace` is not loaded automatically with `fixfoot` (i.e., you will need `\usepackage{fixfoot,xspace}` in the preamble).

Comment: This doesn't work for me. It just repeats the footnote with a new number.

Comment: @Keivan You must compile my MWE two times. The first time you will see  6 footnotes, but the second time only the four showed here.

Comment: The first time this appears in text, the footnote mark is A, as it should be for my document. The second time, though, it's a 1. The mark in the footer is an A, as it should be.

Comment: @EL_DON  With this information and without a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) I am afraid that I would have to be psychic to understand your problem. Please first check if some question about footnote marks in this site help you, otherwise post your own question with a MWE  to show clearly what are you trying (and stating clearly what is the desired result).

Comment: Just add `\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\Alph{footnote}}` to the code in your answer. Only the first instance of `\repnote` gets the `\Alph`

Comment: @EL_DON I  Yes, because the footnote counter is not sed for typing the repeated marks. The package `fixfoot` have not mechanisms to set the format of these marks,  I am afraid that the author think only in arabic numbers.

Comment: This is the only answer that would work in the preamble, but the package is not working for me. The first footnote gets an asterisk. The second, a number. I've open a github bug and this is the question I'm trying to solve: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/674003/declare-footnote-text-before-usage-in-the-preamble

Answer (score 8):

For beamer, the solution using `\footnotemark[\ref{<tag>}]` did not work for me. I used `\textsuperscript` instead.

```
Text with first footnote\footnote{\label{note1}This is the labeled footnote}
and more text with a second footnote\footnote{here}.

In this a paragraph we have a reference to the first
footnote\textsuperscript{\ref{note1}}.
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I stumbled across the same question. Also, for me, `\footnotemark`
did not work. Reason being the **Hyperref-Declarations** in the Template to be used from University. I actually found a similar workaround as posted above, just without the use of additional *usepackages*.

My footnote (the 6st) was labeled `Pereira`. Occuring again in a later spot, I also "pretended" to have a footnote by using the following workaround:
`$^{\ref{pereira}}$`. It looks like a footnote, and if it is clicked it jumps to the correct one :)

---

In summary one can use `\label{footnotelabel}` in the original footnote, and reference a second time via

```
\hyperref[footnotelabel]{$^{\ref*{footnotelabel}}$}
```

Comment: Besides that your readers will probably assume an error, this is a funny idea. +1

Answer (score 3):

There is a particular use-case that I find occurring the most often to me: author and their affiliations cross-reference each other as it was mentioned above. For this particular case I use `authblk` package that works exactly as expected with most of the standard classes of documents:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{authblk}

\begin{document}

\author[1,2]{First Last}
\author[2,3]{Name Surname}
\affil[1]{Institute}
\affil[2]{University}
\affil[3]{Organization}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

The solution for OpTeX:

```
\def\flabel[#1]{\label[#1]\wlabel{\_printfnotemark}}

Text with first footnote\fnote{This is the labeled footnote}\flabel[note1]
and more text with a second footnote\fnote{here}.

In this new paragraph we have a reference to the first
footnote\ref[note1].

\bye
```

Comment: To somebody who gave me negative voice: the original question isn't concerned to LaTeX. There were only LaTeX solutions (why?), I added a nonLaTeX solution.

Answer (score 2):

For me the combination of 

`\footnote{\label{label1}footnote text}` 

for the first footnote and 

`\footref{label1}`

 for the second footnote worked in 

`\documentclass[]{scrbook}`

Comment: IMHO [Clemen's answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/74668/9057) already shows this.

Comment: @Schweinebacke it does :)

Comment: hmm @Schweinebacke, then a tl;dr would be a nice addition to their answer.

Answer (score 1):

Digging this up to add a note on affiliations:

While I originally ended up on this page to do exactly what the OP intended, I agree with Keks Dose - referring to a footnote as in your example seems the more sensible option (and it's something I have frequently seen footnotes that say "See above" in books etc.)

Stephen, any decent LaTeX template should provide means of adding affiliations without having to resort to "normal" footnotes. In the `LNCS` template I'm using quite frequently for papers, this is achieved using the `\inst` command (for institute):

```
\author{First Author\inst{1} \and Second Author\inst{1} \and Another Author\inst{2}}

\institute{
Some university
\and
Some company
}
```

I don't know if there are any packages that do this, but I would think so ...

Comment: Do you mean `\documentclass{llncs}`?

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution:
Define new command \footnoteref in preamble as:

```
\newcommand{\footnoteref}[1]{\textsuperscript{\ref{#1}}}
```

Then in your text:

```
\begin{document}

dummy text with footnote\footnote{Hello world\label{note1}}
then more dummy text with same footnote number\footnoteref{note1}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

The package `footmisc` does the job perfectly for me.

```
\usepackage{footmisc}
Something\footnote{First footnote\label{ref1}} is something which is something which is something\footref{ref1} which is again, something\footref{ref1}.
```

Comment: Is there something new in your answer compared to [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/74668/134805)?

Answer (score 0):

I find the following method easier.

`For instance\footnotemark I can use the same footnote more than  once\footnotemark[\value{footnote}]. \footnotetext{footnote with two references}`

[image]

Ref: https://de.overleaf.com/learn/latex/footnotes#Footnotes_with_multiple_references

Comment: This works, but only if you have no other footnotes in between, because then the counter would have gone up again

Answer (score 0):

Using a different style of reference to the same footnote later on seems a better solution to me by implying that, in effect, the authors are sending the readers to revisit an old footnote. To do otherwise may be more confusing to the reader, who may not realize that, for example, he(she) has been sent to a different page bottom than where the reader was reading. Plus which, the coding for doing it that way is very simple, i.e., for the original footnote and secondary reference one enters

```
\footnote{\label{note1}Whatever the text of the footnote is}
 ...
Blah, blah, blah---See footnote \ref{note1}.
```

This automatically inserts the footnote reference number, e.g., See footnote 18.

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be:

```
my note\footnote{\label{foot:MY_LABEL} Text text}}.
```

And, to use again:

```
Refer Again\textsuperscript{\ref{foot:MY_LABEL}}
```

Answer (score 0):

While the accepted answer works well within the main body of text, it does not work when trying to use footnotes in captions of tables and figures.

In captions we have to rely on combinations of \footnotemark and \footnotetext.

A possible solution then is to create a counter after placing the first footnotemark, and then to set it to have the value of the built-in footnotemark-counter:

```
\begin{table}
\caption[First caption without footnote for use in list of tables]{First caption with footnote\footnotemark}
...
\end{table}

\footnotetext{This is the text for our first footnote}
\newcounter{extrafootnotecounter}
\setcounter{extrafootnotecounter}{\value{footnote}}

Now that we have saved the footnote value for later reference, we can freely add other footnotes\footnotemark
\footnotetext{A completely different footnote}

And then we can use our first footnote again as follows:

\begin{table}
\caption[Second caption without footnote for use in list of tables]{Second caption with the first footnote\footnotemark[\value{extrafootnotecounter}]}
...
\end{table}
```

Note that this solution is not restricted to use within captions.