# One footnote with two marks in the text

Tags: tables, footnotes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reference different places to the same footnote](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35043/reference-different-places-to-the-same-footnote)

How can I have a single footnote but place the mark for it in multiple places on the page (in fact, in a single table). Assume that `\footnote{}` is used liberally in the rest of the document.

Comment: Do you require compatibility with [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref)?

Comment: Not in this case.

Comment: Does the linked post provide a solution to your question?

Answer (score 4):

Use `\footnotemark[num]` the second time you want to place a mark in the text.

Answer (score 4):

**Objection, your honor:**

Have you ever seen that in a book? Probably not. Because: Two footnotemarks numbered with e.g. an "8" raise the question whether it is a typo. But your readers can not come and ask you, if you really meant to do it this way.

Please, if you'd like to refer to the same text, make a footnote saying (maybe in better English than mine):

> ¹ Long sentence at: Wallace, Infinite Jest, p. 1234.
>
> ² See footnote 1.

What you'd like to do is against an old and sensible tradition.

Comment: In technical documentation multiple footnote marks are quite common.

Comment: And how do you distinguish between error and purpose? Especially technical documentations suffering under many flaws, knocked together in minimal time -- especially there it is a no go.

Comment: This is a very good point! Although I see the counter arguments. But this works great for my cause. Just need to figure out, the hyperref will work correclty (1 in "See footnote 1" will lead to footnote 1).