# repetitive footnotes

Tags: footnotes, labels

Is it possible to have the footnotes not to repeat in the same page and take the old number?

In other words, even if the footnote labels are same, can the footnotes have same number.

here is my MWE.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{book}   
\usepackage[para]{footmisc}    % to have footnotes in a line
\begin{document}
This is my test document which has these four footnotes. 
Footnote1\footnote{one}, 
footnote2\footnote{two}, 
footnote3\footnote{three}
and last footnote\footnote{one} to show that fourth one repeats.
\end{document}
```

The question is in the above example, i would like the last footnote to have 1 and not 4.

Comment: Do you want a solution that automatically determines whether the numbers are on the same page or do you just want to have two numbers pointing to the same footnote? In the latter case, this question would be a duplicate of http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35043/reference-different-places-to-the-same-footnote.

Comment: @doncherry, i tried the following answer by Spet in the given link. As he mentioned, it may work for article class. But i am using book class.The following code does not work for me.               \makeatletter
\newcommand\footnoteref[1]{\protected@xdef\@thefnmark{\ref{#1}}\@footnotemark}
\makeatother.  In my case, the second time i use the footnote is for the duplicate footnote.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `fixfoot` package defines a command `\DeclareFixedFootnote`, which you could use as follows:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{book}   
\usepackage[para]{footmisc}    % to have footnotes in a line
\usepackage{fixfoot}
\DeclareFixedFootnote{\myfnone}{one}
\begin{document}
This is my test document which has these four footnotes. 
Footnote1\myfnone{}, 
footnote2\footnote{two}, 
footnote3\footnote{three}
and last footnote\myfnone{} to show that fourth one repeats.
\end{document}
```

The package will take care of the case where its second use is on a later page.

Comment: how do you do this if it repeats in the same page? Also related question for your answer. if the duplicate footnotes are more in number, how do you do it. I mean, foot note 1 and 2 repeats in the same page.

Comment: @Anil You simply declare more fixed footnotes in the preamble. It's slightly inconvenient, but it works. Some LaTeX runs are necessary for the process to stabilize, so don't worry if at the first run a footnote appears twice.