# parcolumns: no footnotes are produced

Tags: footnotes, parcolumns

The footnote number appears in the printed text but I cannot see any footnote when using the `parcolumns` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{parcolumns}
\usepackage[paperheight=9cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\begin{parcolumns}{2}
\colchunk[1]{
Foo
}
\colchunk[2]{
Bar\footnote{Baz}
}
\end{parcolumns}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Is there any workaround to solve this problem?

Comment: I reduced your code a bit, now it is a real MWE. XeLaTeX had nothing to do with the problem.

Answer (score 6):

The [`parcolumns` documentation](http://texdoc.net/pkg/parcolumns) (section 4) says:

> Footnotes are not set in columns.

Here's a way to circumvent this. Note that it only works if you only have *one* footnote per `\colchunk`. Otherwise, you’ll have to fiddle with counters; [Reference different places to the same footnote](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/35043/4012) might be a start. Also note that this solution here might not work with `hyperref`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{parcolumns}
\usepackage[paperheight=9cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\begin{parcolumns}{2}
\colchunk[1]{
Foo\footnotemark
}\footnotetext{Baz the first}
\colchunk[2]{
Bar\footnotemark
}\footnotetext{Baz the second}
\end{parcolumns}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: You also need to be careful about where you place the `\footnotemark`.  Because of the asynchronous page-breaking (I think), it will sometimes be necessary to call `\footnotetext` *before* `\footnotemark` (otherwise, the footnote mark and corresponding footnote text can appear on different pages).