# How does one reference a footnote for a second time?

Tags: footnotes

I have a document in which I have a footnote ("footnote 1") with some special explanation. Later in the document there is a need/want to appeal to this special explanation. In this second instance, I thought about having a footnote ("footnote 2") which goes to the bottom of the page as usual, and in which I just write "See footnote 1".

However, I think it would be better if I could simply refer to footnote 1 in the text, instead of using the middle-man footnote 2. Is this possible?

My failed attempt:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\begin{document}
London is in England\footnote{London is the capital city of England. \label{footnote 1}}.\\
...\\
London is a city\ref{footnote 1}.
\end{document}
```

A picture speaks a thousand words:
[image]

Is this bad practice?

Comment: What is the problem exactly? The referencing seems to work fine, but you should write `London is a city, cf. footnote \ref{footnote 1}`, then it won't look quite as awkward.

Comment: @Anke The problem is that the number ("1") is not in the superscript position.

Comment: Why would you want to have it as a superscript? That would look really weird IMHO... A footnote is a superscript, but the reference is just the number. If, however, you don't want to refer to the footnote, but reuse it, you could just use `$^{\ref{footnote 1}}$`, which looks like really bad tex code, but works...

Comment: An aside: I think footnote should be put *after* the punctuation. See [Do footnoting superscripts go inside or outside punctuation?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/95199/do-footnoting-superscripts-go-inside-or-outside-punctuation)

Comment: @Anke Yeah, that's what I was looking for. Thanks. But, do you think this is bad typographical practice?

Comment: @KevinC -- It really depends on the style.  Many non-English Eurpopean publications put the footnote 'inside' the punctuation mark.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you are using [KOMA-Script](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/koma-script) or [memoir](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/memoir) there is a special macro `\footref`.

If you are using usual `article` class use `\textsuperscript`.

The following MWE shows the possibilitys (I added a comment from @Anke to the question):

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article} % scrartcl article memoir 
\begin{document}
London is in England\footnote{London is the capital city of England. \label{footnote 1}}.

London is a city\textsuperscript{\ref{footnote 1}}.

London is a city$^{\ref{footnote 1}}$.

%London is a city\footref{footnote 1}.  % Only for KOMA-Script or memoir 
\end{document}
```

Comment: `footref` worked for me. Note sure what this KOMA thing is though.

Comment: @User17670 if `\footref` works for you in an other than a KOMA-Script class you might be using a package that happens to load the package `scrextend`. The `memoir` class also provides `\footref`. See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/74668/5049