# How to skip duplication of footnotes

Tags: footnotes

I have redefined footnote command to change mark of footnote in the following way:

> ```
> \newcommand\customfootnote[1]{%
>
>   \begingroup
>
>   \renewcommand\thefootnote{*}\footnote{#1}
>
>   \addtocounter{footnote}{-1}
>
>   \endgroup
>
> }
> ```

But It is need to use the same footnote in several places on the page.

It results in duplication of the same footnotes.

Can you advise me some way how to skip duplication of footnotes?

Thank you in advance.

[image]

Comment: this question might contain a useful answer: [Reference different places to the same footnote](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/35043/579)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could define a `\customfootnotemark` in the same way as `\customfootnote`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a6paper,landscape]{geometry}% making the image for the answer smaller

\newcommand\customfootnote[1]{%
  \begingroup
    \renewcommand\thefootnote{*}\footnote{#1}%
    \addtocounter{footnote}{-1}%
  \endgroup
}
\newcommand*{\customfootnotemark}{%
  \begingroup
    \renewcommand*{\thefootnote}{*}%
    \footnotemark
    \addtocounter{footnote}{-1}%
  \endgroup
}

\begin{document}
  % text from \lipsum[2], package `lipsum`
  Nam dui ligula\customfootnote{Here is a custom footnote},
  fringilla a, euismod sodales,
  sollicitudin vel, wisi. Morbi auctor lorem non justo. Nam lacus
  libero, pretium at, lobortis vitae, ultricies et, tellus. Donec
  aliquet, tortor\customfootnotemark\ sed accumsan bibendum,
  erat ligula aliquet magna,
  vitae ornare odio metus a mi. Morbi ac orci et nisl hendrerit
  mollis. Suspendisse\footnote{A conventional footnote} ut massa. Cras nec ante
  Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes,
  nascetur ridiculus mus. Aliquam\customfootnotemark\ tincidunt urna.
  Nulla ullamcorper vestibulum turpis. Pellent esque cursus luctus mauris.
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Limitation: If `\customfootnotemark` goes to a new page, it needs to be replaced by `\customfootnote{...}`, if the footnote text should also appear on the new page.

Comment: the `fixfoot` package provides for multiple uses of the same footnote text, with only one mark per page of text.  doesn't cope with hyperref, which hadn't got above my horizon when i wrote the package (199x), but it probably wouldn't be impossibly difficult to add it.  (doing so would require someone actually to want the change, which doesn't seem likely.)