# How to merge multiple footnotes?

Tags: footnotes

Is it possible to merge multiple footnote?

For example: `"Solution A\footenote{Created by person C} and solution B\footnote{Created by person C} are great".`

The footnote should then be just one with the text `"Created by person C"`.

Comment: Does http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35043/reference-different-places-to-the-same-footnote help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution is the `fixfoot` package. You must compile twice to see only a foot note.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{fixfoot}
\DeclareFixedFootnote*{\personC}{Created by person C.}
\begin{document}
Solution A\personC and solution B\personC are great.
\end{document}
```

Comment: The "*{..}" part caused issues for me. This worked:

\DeclareFixedFootnote\personC{Created by person C.}