# Custom footnotes in the authblk package

Tags: footnotes, authblk

I would like to create a special footnote such that more than one location is mapped to the same footnote. This is covered elsewhere ([Reference different places to the same footnote](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35043/reference-different-places-to-the-same-footnote)), but I am running in to trouble as I'm trying to use it in the authors list with the authblk package (the custom footnote is `\CoAuthorMark`). Other things may be wrong with this, but I haven't gotten to the point of experimentation yet.

Alternatively, is there a way to do this with \thanks?

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[affil-it]{authblk}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}


\title{An efficient method for exploiting midichlorians in weak life-forms}

\author[1,2]{Darth Vader\footnote{Contributed equally.}}%

\newcounter{CoAuthor}

% The order may be wrong on these next two:
\setcounter{CoAuthor}{\value{footnote}}
\edef\CoAuthorMark{\footnotemark[\value{CoAuthor}]}

\author[2,3]{Darth Sidious\CoAuthorMark%
  \thanks{Electronic address: \texttt{palpatine@empire.gove}; Corresponding author}}

\affil[1]{Office of the Supreme Commander of the Imperial Forces, The Galactic Empire, The Bridge, Executor}
\affil[2]{Order of the Sith Lords, LiMerge Power Building, The Works, Coruscant}
\affil[3]{Office of the Emperor of the Galaxy, The Galactic Empire, 1000 Imperial Palace, 2 Main St. Coruscant}


\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

The error message I get with the above is:

```
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again>
                   \c@CoAuthor
l.16 ...AuthorMark{\footnotemark[\value{CoAuthor}]
                                                  }
```

But I usually get something like this:

```
! Use of \\author doesn't match its definition.
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The new counter doesn't seem necessary, as you just use the current value of `footnote`; also `\footnotemark` should be protected in the `\edef` and `\value{CoAuthor}` should be `\arabic{CoAuthor}`, because `\value{CoAuthor}` doesn't expand to the number, but only to the internal name of the counter.

Actually, you don't need `\edef` at all.

Finally, `\CoAuthorMark` must be protected in `\author`.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[affil-it]{authblk}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}


\title{An efficient method for exploiting midichlorians in weak life-forms}

\author[1,2]{Darth Vader\footnote{Contributed equally.}}

% The order may be wrong on these next two:
\newcommand\CoAuthorMark{\footnotemark[\arabic{footnote}]} % get the current value
\author[2,3]{Darth Sidious\protect\CoAuthorMark
  \thanks{Electronic address: \texttt{palpatine@empire.gove}; Corresponding author}}

\affil[1]{%
  Office of the Supreme Commander of the Imperial Forces, 
  The Galactic Empire, The Bridge, Executor}
\affil[2]{%
  Order of the Sith Lords, LiMerge Power Building, The Works, Coruscant}
\affil[3]{%
  Office of the Emperor of the Galaxy, The Galactic Empire, 
  1000 Imperial Palace, 2 Main St. Coruscant}


\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It seems that only the dagger (from `\thanks`) is typeset for the second author.

Comment: @bbarker Well, I don't know *what* you want, because you didn't explain it.

Comment: Sorry that it wasn't clear. I'd expect to see: Darth Vader*1,2 and Darth Sidious*†2,3

Comment: @bbarker Is it good, now?

Comment: Yes! I need to double check, but it seems my main mistake (at least at some point in trying) was that I was not using `\arabic`.

Comment: Actually, both \value and \arabic seemed to work in this context. My problem seems to stem from how I used the new counter. I realize isn't needed for this particular example. But let's say you increment footnote one or more times before wanting to use the old symbol ('*' in this example). In that case, it seems useful to somehow save `footnote` to some other counter. But when I try this using e.g. `\setcounter{CoAuthor}{\value{footnote}}`, no symbol is displayed where the following command is called: `\newcommand\CoAuthorMark{\footnotemark[\value{CoAuthor}]}`. (I tried `\arabic` too).

Comment: @bbarker The counter is not set when `\author` is processed, but only when the author field is used by `\maketitle`, that's the problem.

Comment: Got it, if I use `\protect\setcounter...` inside the `\author` command, it will work.

Comment: @littleO The `titlepage` option changes the meaning of `\maketitle`

Comment: Thanks. How would someone indicate the corresponding author when using the authblk package and the titlepage option?

Comment: @littleO That's a whole new question

Comment: I just asked it as a new question, if you have a chance to answer it'd help a lot.  Thanks.