# Custom footnotes with authblk package in a tikzposter

Tags: tikzposter, authblk

I would like to use authblk in a tikzposter documentclass, together with custom footnodes like in this post: [Custom footnotes in the authblk package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/173325/custom-footnotes-in-the-authblk-package)

Changing the documentclass as in the following code leads to the symbols ∗ and † being replaced by the numbers 3 and 34. To me this looks like some symbols are defined in a different way in tikzposters, but I don't know how to change this. I would be happy for any help.

```
\documentclass[25pt, a0paper, landscape]{tikzposter}
\usepackage[affil-it]{authblk}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\title{An efficient method for exploiting midichlorians}

\author[1,2]{Darth Vader\footnote{Contributed equally.}}

% The order may be wrong on these next two:
\newcommand\CoAuthorMark{\footnotemark[\arabic{footnote}]} % get the current value
\author[2,3]{Darth Sidious\protect\CoAuthorMark
  \thanks{Electronic address: \texttt{palpatine@empire.gove}; Corresponding author}}

\affil[1]{%
  Office of the Supreme Commander of the Imperial Forces, 
  The Galactic Empire, The Bridge, Executor}
\affil[2]{%
  Order of the Sith Lords, LiMerge Power Building, The Works, Coruscant}
\affil[3]{%
  Office of the Emperor of the Galaxy, The Galactic Empire, 
  1000 Imperial Palace, 2 Main St. Coruscant}


\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: For a poster I'd simply hand make the title part according to your preferences.

Comment: That would be also ok for me, but I also couldn't find how to add two lines, similar to the footnote below the authors