# Proper way to reuse footnotes in Latex

Tags: pdftex, cross-referencing, footnotes, labels

I don't know how to word this, but if I want output like so

> The Universe* is full of all universes+ even though the Universe* is the same size as any one of the universes+
>
> *The Universe formed of all the stars and planets
>
> +The alternate universes

I can try modifying `\footnote{}` commands to make this happen, as explained in this answer ([Reference different places to the same footnote:spet](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/35044/8384)). However, another answer in there cautions against it ([Reference different places to the same footnote:spet](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/44643/8384)).

How do authors usually tackle this situation? Specifically, these symbols need to be embedded in a table (which I have inside minipages), then the legend would need to be immediately below the table/minipage.

**Minimal Working Example**

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}[c]{0.9\textwidth}%
   \footnotesize
   \begin{center}
      \begin{tabular}{| l | l |}
         \hline
         Category & Value\\\hline
         Bla & $60^{+}$\\\hline
         Bla & $60^{*}$\\\hline
         Bla & $30^{+}$\\\hline
         Bla & $90^{*}$\\
         \hline
      \end{tabular}
   \end{center}
\end{minipage}

\begin{itemize}
   \item[+] Rounded up
   \item[*] Rounded Down
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: A complete example would make it a lot easier to help. What does the table look like? I assume you mean you have a `minipage` inside a `table`. Or you don't mean a `table`. But actually code would  be a lot easier to work with!

Answer (score 3):

There are likely many ways. Here are two -- which, in a way, abuses the `longtable` environment because, inside a `minipage` environment, you will surely not be building a table that is longer than one page. However, it does provide for a simpler syntax than some other solutions because `longtable` can handle footnotes normally. (Note that it is not always considered typographically sound to use "normal" footnotes with tables.)

**The `memoir` class**

```
\documentclass[12pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{longtable}
\begin{document}
The Universe%
\footnote{\label{uni}%
  The Universe formed of all the stars and planets} %
is full of all universes%
\footnote{\label{alt}%
  The alternate universes} %
even though the Universe\footref{uni} is the same size as any one of
the universes\footref{alt}

\noindent
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\begin{longtable}{cc}
One\footnote{\label{a}1st} & Two\footnote{\label{b}2nd}\\
Three\footref{a}           & Four\footref{b}\\
\end{longtable}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

**The `footmisc` package**

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{footmisc,longtable}
\begin{document}
The Universe%
\footnote{\label{uni}%
  The Universe formed of all the stars and planets} %
is full of all universes%
\footnote{\label{alt}%
  The alternate universes} %
even though the Universe\footref{uni} is the same size as any one of
the universes\footref{alt}

\noindent
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\begin{longtable}{cc}
One\footnote{\label{a}1st} & Two\footnote{\label{b}2nd}\\
Three\footref{a}           & Four\footref{b}\\
\end{longtable}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

You might note some similarities in syntax....

Comment: What would be the point of a `longtable` in a `minipage` exactly?

Comment: @cfr -- Nice catch. I first didn't note that the OP was set on using minipages or tables, just on how to get a `\footref`. But the other reason is that `longtable` handles footnotes (and I am not a fan of `threeparttable`). Besides, as you'll note, the code involved is actually noticeably simpler when you put the `longtable` in a `minipage` when compared to `minipage`, `threeparttable`, and `tabular`.

Comment: Ah, I see. (+1) but I'd recommend explaining that in the answer i.e. that the use of `longtable` (or similar) is important to your solution. I'm not keen on `threeparttable`. I just haven't found anything better.  (I'm using it inside `table`.) But I do like having the notes within the table - I just don't like the non-automated bit.

Comment: @cfr -- True.  Added a little more to my answer.

Comment: However, I'm getting more enthusiastic about `threeparttablex`. I got it to automate table note numbering today, creating an unholy mixture by combining  it with `enumitem` ;).

Comment: @cfr -- Ah, yes, the automation of the `-x` version does indeed look promising.

Answer (score 2):

I would create the notes as part of the overall table structure using, for example, `threeparttable`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}[c]{0.9\textwidth}%
   \footnotesize
   \begin{center}
     \begin{threeparttable}
      \begin{tabular}{| l | l |}
         \hline
         Category & Value\\\hline
         Bla & $60$\tnote{+}\\\hline
         Bla & $60$\tnote{*}\\\hline
         Bla & $30$\tnote{+}\\\hline
         Bla & $90$\tnote{*}\\
         \hline
      \end{tabular}
      \begin{tablenotes}
        \item[+]Rounded up
        \item[*]Rounded Down
      \end{tablenotes}
     \end{threeparttable}
   \end{center}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

[image: notes in table]

However, I would also recommend reading a bit about the typesetting of professional quality tables. The `booktabs` documentation is one good, if occasionally extreme, place to start.

Taking its advice to heart, I might use something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{threeparttable,booktabs,array}
\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}[c]{0.9\textwidth}%
   \footnotesize
   \begin{center}
     \begin{threeparttable}
       \begin{tabular}{l>{$}l<{$}}
         \toprule
         Category & Value\\\midrule
         Bla & 60\tnote{+}\\
         Bla & 60\tnote{*}\\
         Bla & 30\tnote{+}\\
         Bla & 90\tnote{*}\\
         \bottomrule
      \end{tabular}
      \begin{tablenotes}
        \item[+]Rounded up
        \item[*]Rounded down
      \end{tablenotes}
     \end{threeparttable}
   \end{center}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

[image: prettier notes in table]

I also wonder if you really need these to be in `minipage` environments. This looks like an overly complex structure. However, it is difficult to know for sure, of course, without more context.