# Komascript: remove (sub)-section from TOC

Tags: table-of-contents, koma-script

I'm working on a document where I want to exclude several (sub)sections on different toc-depths from being listed inside the TOC.

Example:

```
Chapter 1
Section 1.1
Subsection 1.1.1 << remove
Subsection 1.1.2 << remove

Section 1.2
Section 1.3 << remove
Section 1.4
```

Excluding these sections via `tocdepth` isn't possible for me. So my idea was to have modified `\chapter*`, `\section*`, `\subsection*` ... commands that generate the headings (including the formatting and numbering) as usual but don't list the entries inside the TOC.

Is there a way to get this to work?

Comment: You can change tocdepth locally with `tocvsec2`: https://ctan.org/pkg/tocvsec2

Comment: Short answer (because of missing MWE): If you use an empty string for the ToC-entry it automatically will not be added. You can do this using the optional argument of the (sub)section command.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the extended optional argument of the sectioning commands. KOMA-Script will automatically omit empty ToC entries. To switch on the parsing for the extended optional argument, you have to use one of the following options:

- `headings=optiontotocandhead`: Use the not extended optional argument for both the ToC and the running head
- `headings=optiontotoc`: Use the not extended optional argument for the ToC only but the mandatory argument for the running head
- `headings=optiontohead`: Use the not extended optional argument for the running head, but the mandatory argument for the ToC

So you can either use:

```
\documentclass[
  headings=optiontotocandhead% switch on extended optional argument parsing
                             % for sectioning commands
]{scrbook}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{\subsectiontocdepth}% generally show part, chapter,
                                          % section and subsection in the ToC

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Chapter 1}
\lipsum[1]
\section{Section 1.1}
\lipsum[2]
\subsection[tocentry={}]{Subsection 1.1.1}% no ToC entry
\lipsum[3]
\subsection[tocentry={}]{Subsection 1.1.2}% no ToC entry
\lipsum[4]
\section{Section 1.2}
\lipsum[5]
\section[tocentry={}]{Section 1.3}% no ToC entry
\lipsum[6]
\section{Section 1.4}
\lipsum[7]
\subsection{Subsection 1.5}
\lipsum[8]
\end{document}
```

or

```
\documentclass[
  headings=optiontotoc% switch on extended optional argument parsing
                      % for sectioning commands and restrict it to the ToC
]{scrbook}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{\subsectiontocdepth}% generally show part, chapter,
                                          % section and subsection in the ToC

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Chapter 1}
\lipsum[1]
\section{Section 1.1}
\lipsum[2]
\subsection[]{Subsection 1.1.1}% no ToC entry
\lipsum[3]
\subsection[]{Subsection 1.1.2}% no ToC entry
\lipsum[4]
\section{Section 1.2}
\lipsum[5]
\section[]{Section 1.3}% no ToC entry
\lipsum[6]
\section{Section 1.4}
\lipsum[7]
\subsection{Subsection 1.5}
\lipsum[8]
\end{document}
```

to get

[image: resulting ToC]

Answer (score 0):

### Don't do it.

---

> Is there a way to get this to work?

**No.** As described in the answer of [Schweinebacke](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/9057/schweinebacke) you can get a table of contents with discontinuous numbering.

But it will not work, because your readers just will just assume that your toc is buggy.

This [again](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/44643/4736) is an idea without any consideration of the readers expectations. Don't do it. Readers can not come back and ask you.