# How to give multiple authors same footnote?

Tags: pdftex, sharelatex

I am trying to give equal credits to two authors, but I am failing to put this in latex. I did it a bit unconventionally and my latex code is as follows:

```
\documentclass[sigconf]{acmart}
\fancyhead{}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\settopmatter{printfolios=false}
\settopmatter{printacmref=false} % Removes citation information below abstract
\renewcommand\footnotetextcopyrightpermission[1]{}
\usepackage{booktabs} % For formal tables
\author{A*, B*, and C}
\thanks{*these authors contributed equally}
\affiliation{%
  \institution{D}
  \city{E} 
  \state{F} 
%  \postcode{0}
}
\email{{a,b,c}@gmail.com}
\begin{document}
\title{TITLE}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot]

It does not look original to me. So, if there is any other solution, please kindly share.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: [This question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35043/reference-different-places-to-the-same-footnote) and its answers may be of help.

Answer (score 1):

`acmart` (now) supports this directly. From [the documentation](https://www.acm.org/binaries/content/assets/publications/consolidated-tex-template/acmart.pdf):

> Sometimes one may need to have the same footnote connected to several authors.
> The command `\authornotemark[⟨number⟩]` adds just the footnote mark, for example,
>
> ```
> \author{A. U. Thor}
> \authornote{Both authors contributed equally to the paper}
> ...
> \author{A. N. Other}
> \authornotemark[1]
> ```

With other document classes, the generic `footnotemark` approach ([linked above](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35043/reference-different-places-to-the-same-footnote)) might be the right thing. For instance, sometimes you might have to use `\thanks` on one author and `\footnotemark` on the other, but it depends on how the style file does author names.