# Single footnote for multiple *distinct* references

Tags: footnotes

Say I have text like the following:

> This sentence contains one reference^1 to a footnote and also another one^2.

where `^1` and `^2` stand for superscript footnote references.

How can I then have a footnote at the bottom of the page as such?

> 1, 2 This is the footnote text.

As far as I'm concerned, this is the most reasonable way for multiple positions in a text to refer to the same footnote, since repeating the same superscript number might be confusing. (If someone can show convince me there's a good alternative though, I'm open to that.) Anyway, is there a package to do this? If not, what's a good manual solution?

Comment: If you do decide that you can use the same footnote number, this question shows a way to do it: [Reference different places to the same footnote](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/35043)

Comment: Hm, I would find it very confusing, if there were footnotes like `1,10 text` and `2,8 text` and `3,5,7 text`. To find footnote 5 I would have to skim all footnotes numbers to check if it is in the list. It is much easier if they are ordered.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Would do you mean 'ordered'?

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thanks. I wonder if that would be confusing (look like a typo), but I might opt for it anyway.

Comment: I mean that footnotes should be one after the other at the bottom. I expect there to find `1 footnote text    2 footnote  text 3 footnote text `

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Yes, they may be slightly easier to locate at a quick glance that way. However, I have also seen the style i suggested in published works.

Comment: well I haven't, and I'm not aware of an existing implementation of this style. It would be certainly not trivial to implement . You would have to store the pages of the footnotes and collect the numbers in labels as you wouldn't want to have this for footnotes on different pages. Manually, below a table it is naturally easy, simply use threeparttable.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Okay, I'll consider just using the same-number solution then.

Comment: Ah, now I fully see the issue... even with the same number, if the marks happen to be on two different pages, then there's a problem. I don't think the above solution that @barbarabeeton linked to solves that. In such a case, I would want two different footnotes, although normally one would suffice.

Comment: Ah, the fixnote package does what I want here.