# Multiple references to the same footnote

Tags: lyx

I need to refer the same footnote in different lines. I am using `scrbook` class. I read [Reference different places to the same footnote](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35043/reference-different-places-to-the-same-footnote) and tried in following way:

First time referencing`\footnote{\label{footnote}text}`.

Second time referencing`\footref{footnote}`.

But it gives the following output. Would anyone please suggest for the second time referencing how to display only the number instead of "footnote no."? Thank you.

[image]

Update: Minimal working example

```
\documentclass{scrbook}\begin{document}
\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand{\ref}[1]{\mbox{\autoref{#1}}}}
\newlength{\abc}
\settowidth{\abc}{\space}
\AtBeginDocument{%
\addto\extrasenglish{
 \renewcommand{\equationautorefname}{\hspace{-\abc}}
 \renewcommand{\sectionautorefname}{sec.\negthinspace}
 \renewcommand{\subsectionautorefname}{sec.\negthinspace}
 \renewcommand{\subsubsectionautorefname}{sec.\negthinspace}
 \renewcommand{\figureautorefname}{Fig.\negthinspace}
 \renewcommand{\tableautorefname}{Tab.\negthinspace}
}
}

\usepackage[figure]{hypcap}

First time referencing\footnote{\label{footnote}text}.

Second time referencing\footref{footnote}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: If all I do is wrap your code in `\documentclass{scrbook}\begin{document}` and `\end{document}` I do not get that result. There must be some other code or package in your document you haven't shown that is responsible. Please post a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) showing the problem.

Comment: @frabjous, this is a book template and actually there are lots of packages included in the preamble. I even could not understand which package is responsible for that. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: Welcome to tex.se! In addition to frabjous's link, see here for some LyX-specific info: https://wiki.lyx.org/FAQ/MinimalExample

Comment: I updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

Have you though about simply using `\label` in the first time that the footnote appears and `\ref` to make reference for the footnote?

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\begin{document}
This is the text and reference to footnote.\footnote{\label{fn}Text of footnote.}

Need to make reference again here to the same text of a previous footnote.\textsuperscript{\ref{fn}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Don't misuse maths mode. `\textsuperscript{}` is designed for superscript text. But, in any case, there are specialised commands for this situation and it is a bad idea to mark your document up based on appearances. What if you decide you need end notes rather than footnotes, for example?

Comment: @cfr Good point. I changed the answer with the use of `\textsuperscript{}`. You are right about being a solution that might not work permanently. But it is a simple solution that can be helpful in certain cases

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `scrbook` has its own idea about `\footref`. Use your own definition like

```
% footrefprob.tex  SE 640730

\documentclass{scrbook}

\renewcommand{\footref}[1]{\textsuperscript{\ref{#1}}}

\begin{document}

First time referencing\footnote{\label{footnote}text}.

Second time referencing\footref{footnote}.

\end{document}

Your MWE, below, had several problems. Did you actually compile it?

\documentclass{scrbook}\begin{document}
\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand{\ref}[1]{\mbox{\autoref{#1}}}}
\newlength{\abc}
\settowidth{\abc}{\space}
\AtBeginDocument{%
\addto\extrasenglish{
 \renewcommand{\equationautorefname}{\hspace{-\abc}}
 \renewcommand{\sectionautorefname}{sec.\negthinspace}
 \renewcommand{\subsectionautorefname}{sec.\negthinspace}
 \renewcommand{\subsubsectionautorefname}{sec.\negthinspace}
 \renewcommand{\figureautorefname}{Fig.\negthinspace}
 \renewcommand{\tableautorefname}{Tab.\negthinspace}
}
}

\usepackage[figure]{hypcap}

First time referencing\footnote{\label{footnote}text}.

Second time referencing\footref{footnote}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

The `memoir` class (a superset of `book` and `report`) has a `\footref` macro that does what you want, which is what I would have thought was the general desire.

Comment: Yes, I compiled it. It shows several errors. I added ```\renewcommand{\footref}[1]{\textsuperscript{\ref{#1}}}``` in the preamble, but that does not resolve the problem. This is the book template that my teacher gave. I cannot delete any existing code. I can only add if required.

Comment: @user268373 Did my MWE work for you? If it did then you have problems with your template (whatever a template is). You say you cannot delete any existing code but you can always redefine it (`\renewcommand...` in general or `\renewcommand{\acommand}{}` to effectively nullify  (delete) it.)

Comment: it works if I create a new file. With my template, it does not work. Looks like there is some problems with my template.