# Beamer repeated citation new number

Tags: beamer

I am discussing a topic on multiple frames, and I want to cite the original article on each slide using footfullcite. However beamer increases the citation number on each frame. Is there a way to tell beamer to increase it only if I refer to a new article?

Here is my approach:

```
\documentclass[mathserif]{beamer}
   \usepackage[style=verbose,backend=biber]{biblatex}

   \setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]
   \setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]

   \renewcommand{\footnotesize}{\tiny}

   \bibliography{refs}


   \begin{document}
       \frame{\frametitle{Title}
       \footfullcite{art}
   }   
   \frame{\frametitle{Title}
       \footfullcite{art}
   }   

\end{document}
```

Comment: try `\addtocounter{footnote}{-1}` where you do not want the counter to be increased

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[turning the previous comment into an answer]**

Add

> \addtocounter{footnote}{-1}

wherever you do not want the counter to be increased

Answer (score 1):

I think you can also use

```
\footnotemark[\value{footnote}]
```

to show the current value of the counter without increasing it. And I guess you could use it to indicate a given value as well.

Taken from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27763/beamer-multiple-references-to-the-same-footnote)