# Latex Beamer same reference on different slides with footcite

Tags: beamer, bibtex, citing, footnotes

I use the customized footcite command from [Inline citations with only author, title and year](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/123104/inline-citations-with-only-author-title-and-year):

```
\newcommand{\customcite}[1]{\citeauthor{#1}, \citetitle{#1}, \citeyear{#1}}
```

My problem is now, when I have the same reference on multiple slides, the footnote number is increased. I would like to have the same number for the same source on every slide where it appears.

I found something with `savefootnote`, but this seems to be very complicated: [Beamer: multiple references to the same footnote](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27763/beamer-multiple-references-to-the-same-footnote). Also, it is only possible to store one reference at a time, but I would like to have 3 references each on 2 pages.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
%\documentclass[handout,11pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usetheme{Madrid}


% literature
% only for this example, otherwise in .bib file
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Harshman1970,
    author = {and others Harshman, Richard A},
    doi = {10.1134/S0036023613040165},
    file = {:C$\backslash$:/Users/Isi/Documents/Research/Tensors/TensorsDocumentation/Literature/Harshman{\_}CPD.pdf:pdf},
    issn = {00360236},
    journal = {UCLA Working Papers in Phonetics},
    pages = {1--84},
    title = {{Foundations of the PARAFAC procedure: Models and conditions for an" explanatory" multimodal factor analysis}},
    volume = {16},
    year = {1970}
}
@article{Hitchcock1927,
    author = {Hitchcock, Frank L.},
    doi = {10.1002/sapm192761164},
    file = {:C$\backslash$:/Users/Isi/Documents/Research/Tensors/TensorsDocumentation/Literature/Hitchcock{\_}cpd.pdf:pdf},
    issn = {0097-1421},
    journal = {Journal of Mathematics and Physics},
    number = {1-4},
    pages = {164--189},
    title = {{The Expression of a Tensor or a Polyadic as a Sum of Products}},
    volume = {6},
    year = {1927}
}
@article{Carroll1970,
    doi = {10.1007/BF02310791},
    file = {:C$\backslash$:/Users/Isi/Documents/Research/Tensors/TensorsDocumentation/Literature/Carrol{\_}Chang{\_}CPD.pdf:pdf},
    issn = {00333123},
    journal = {Psychometrika},
    number = {3},
    pages = {283--319},
    title = {{Analysis of individual differences in multidimensional scaling via an n-way generalization of "Eckart-Young" decomposition}},
    volume = {35},
    year = {1970}
}

\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[style=verbose,backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\newcommand{\customfootcite}[1]{\footnote{\citeauthor{#1}, \citetitle{#1}, \citeyear{#1}}}



\begin{document}
    \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

    \begin{frame}{Slide 1\customfootcite{Harshman1970}\customfootcite{Hitchcock1927}\customfootcite{Carroll1970}}
        some text
    \end{frame}

    \begin{frame}{Slide 2\customfootcite{Harshman1970}\customfootcite{Hitchcock1927}\customfootcite{Carroll1970}}
    some figure
    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Gives this:

[image]

I want the second slide to have the numbers 1,2,3 again (instead of 4,5,6).

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Welcome to SX. To clarify your question: you would like to have on slide two, references numbering from 1 to 3 again ?

Comment: @R.N Yes, exactly. I updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to use as a footnote symbol the number that could be used in the bibliography with a numeric style. So if you want to print the bibliography at the end of your presentation yo will have something coherent.

I also recommand to use a `\DeclareCiteCommand` which is more flexible than a usual `\newcommand`. It can also be useful to use `biber` rather than `bibtex` option.

Just for the record, I think you have a problem with the author name of your bib entry `Carroll1970`.

So here is my suggestion, with some extra `footnote` to test the different styles plus an extra slide to print the bibliography:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

% literature
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Harshman1970,
    author = {and others Harshman, Richard A},
    doi = {10.1134/S0036023613040165},
    issn = {00360236},
    journal = {UCLA Working Papers in Phonetics},
    pages = {1--84},
    title = {{Foundations of the PARAFAC procedure: Models and conditions for an" explanatory" multimodal factor analysis}},
    volume = {16},
    year = {1970}
}
@article{Hitchcock1927,
    author = {Hitchcock, Frank L.},
    doi = {10.1002/sapm192761164},
    issn = {0097-1421},
    journal = {Journal of Mathematics and Physics},
    number = {1-4},
    pages = {164--189},
    title = {{The Expression of a Tensor or a Polyadic as a Sum of Products}},
    volume = {6},
    year = {1927}
}
@article{Carroll1970,
    doi = {10.1007/BF02310791},
    author = {Carroll, Chang},
    issn = {00333123},
    journal = {Psychometrika},
    number = {3},
    pages = {283--319},
    title = {{Analysis of individual differences in multidimensional scaling via an n-way generalization of "Eckart-Young" decomposition}},
    volume = {35},
    year = {1970}
}
\end{filecontents}

% Change the footnote style with letters to avoid confusion.
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\alph{footnote}}

% Add sorting=None to keep the calling order.
\usepackage[style=numeric, sorting=none, backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

% Change the style of the printing biblio to let appear the numbers like in the footnote
\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}{\insertbiblabel}

% Define the new cite command using the footnote
\DeclareCiteCommand{\testcommand}
    {\usebibmacro{prenote}} 
    {%
        \renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\arabic{footnote}}% Switch to footnote with numbers.
        \footnotemark[\thefield{labelnumber}]% Add the mark corresponding to the number entry.
        \footnotetext[\thefield{labelnumber}]{%  Add the footnote text with same number entry.
            \printnames{labelname}% The name 
            \setunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}% separator
            \printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}% The title
            \setunit{\addperiod\space}% separator
            \printfield{year}% The year
        }%
        \renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\alph{footnote}}% Switch back to footnote with letters.
    }
    {\multicitedelim}
    {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\secondcommand}
    {\usebibmacro{prenote}} 
    {%
        \renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\arabic{footnote}}% Switch to footnote with numbers.
        \footnotemark[\thefield{labelnumber}]% Add the mark corresponding to the number entry.
        \renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\alph{footnote}}% Switch back to footnote with letters.
    }
    {\multicitedelim}
    {\usebibmacro{postnote}}


\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}{Slide 1\testcommand{Harshman1970}\testcommand{Hitchcock1927}\testcommand{Carroll1970}}
        some text \footnote{test} 
    \end{frame}

    \begin{frame}{Slide 2\testcommand{Harshman1970}\testcommand{Hitchcock1927}\testcommand{Carroll1970}}
        some figure \footnote{test}  
    \end{frame}

    \begin{frame}{Slide 2\testcommand{Harshman1970}\testcommand{Hitchcock1927}\testcommand{Carroll1970}}
            some figure \footnote{test}  
            Some citation \secondcommand{Hitchcock1927}
    \end{frame}

    \begin{frame}[noframenumbering,plain,allowframebreaks]{References}
        \printbibliography[heading=none]
    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

## Edit

The `secondcommand` can be used in case of multiple citation on the same slide. Otherwise you will get several time the same footnote.

Comment: This solved my problem! Thanks a lot. :) And yes, there was a problem with the author, but I fixed it now.

Comment: I really like this and use it in all my presentations. However, now I have the problem that I have to items on the same slide referring to the same footnote. The number behind the two items is the same, which is correct, but the reference appears twice in the footnote. Do you have an idea how to avoid this? I tried using \footnotemark, but the footnotes before are somehow not counted - at least, for me there is an "a" printed on the slides when I write \footnotemark

Comment: @Isi It would deserve a new question, but anyway I edit my answer for this kind of cases. I hope it solves your problem.

Comment: Yes, it solves my problem. Thank you so much! Unfortunately I cannot give you a second thumbs up :( :D

Comment: @Isi This is why usually people ask for a new question. However, you can still upvote the answer (different than accepted answer). :)

Comment: I have upvoted it, but I don't have enough reputation that this is visible. I alao can't upvote comments :(